# Flutter video player from stream response api

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I am trying to read a stream in chunks and play them to video_player Flutter, but it does not seem to be working.

I have created an API with the help of Asynchronously streaming video with ASP.NET Web API which return the Stream outputStream as return value.

Thanks.